# when is execution plans in SQL Server generated?

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan

In a stored procedure in SQL Server, when is the actual SQL query plans generated? When the SQL is run for the first time or when the stored procedure is compiled? Any idea how expensive the generation of query plans is in comparison to Oracle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a query is run, SQL Server will check to see if an execution plan already exists for that  query in the execution plan cache. If it finds one, it can reuse that execution plan. If it doesn't find one in the cache, it then generates a plan, puts in the cache ready for subsequent calls to reuse, and then executes the query. So it does this at the time when the query is executed.

How long a plan stays in the cache for is down to a number of factors, including:
- how often that plan is used
- how much "value" that plan offers
- memory pressure on the server

So a given query could have an execution plan generated multiple times over the course of a given period, if it's plan is not managing to stay in the cache. Also, when SQL Server restarts, the cache is cleared.

There's a good MSDN article on [Execution Plan Caching and Reuse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181055.aspx)

Comment: Thats fine, but can you expand on stored procedures (not random tsql queries) as the OP asked?

Comment: @astander - by "query", I'm including adhoc tsql statements/parameterised tsql statements/stored procedures all under that - I don't feel there's any reason to distinguish here

Comment: I think you should. Stored procedures are different from ad hoc queries. Saved execution plans/forced recompiles/parameter sniffing just to mention a few off the top of my head...

Comment: If I understand it correctly, no execution plan is generated when you compile your stored procedure? Only when you actually run the stored procedure query plans are generated for the SQL that is run inside the procedure?

Comment: @KTrum - When you create a stored procedure, it doesn't compile it ("compile" can be a misleading term here, don't think in the sense of e.g. .NET) and no execution plan is generated at that point. So yes, it's only at execution time that a plan is generated.

Comment: @AdaTheDev, I figured the t-sql gets compiled when you create the procedure (the procedural parts that is)? The actual SQL doesn't get compiled, but generates an execution plan when it is run.

Comment: Ah, t-sql seems to be interpreted, not compiled. I didn't know that :)